# Await and ContinueWith

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I was trying out `System.Json` (Beta) from NuGet.  Also, trying to understand this new `async`/`await` stuff, just started Tinkering with Visual Studio 2012.

Wondering if using a `ContinueWith` if the `await` blocks until the whole thing is complete?

E.g, is this:

```
JsonValue json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith<JsonValue>(respTask => JsonValue.Parse(respTask.Result));
```

The same as:

```
        string respTask = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JsonValue json = await Task.Factory.StartNew<JsonValue>(() => JsonValue.Parse(respTask));
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are similar but not identical.

`ContinueWith` returns a `Task` representing the continuation. So, to take your example:

```
JsonValue json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    .ContinueWith<JsonValue>(respTask => JsonValue.Parse(respTask.Result));
```

Consider just the expression:

```
                       response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    .ContinueWith<JsonValue>(respTask => JsonValue.Parse(respTask.Result));
```

The result of this expression is a `Task` representing the continuation scheduled by `ContinueWith`.

So, when you `await` that expression:

```
                 await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    .ContinueWith<JsonValue>(respTask => JsonValue.Parse(respTask.Result));
```

You are indeed `await`ing the `Task` returned by `ContinueWith`, and the assignment to the `json` variable will not take place until the `ContinueWith` continuation has completed:

```
JsonValue json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    .ContinueWith<JsonValue>(respTask => JsonValue.Parse(respTask.Result));
```

---

Generally speaking, I avoid `ContinueWith` when writing `async` code. There's nothing *wrong* with it, but it's a bit low-level and the syntax is more awkward.

In your case, I would do something like this:

```
var responseValue = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var json = JsonValue.Parse(responseValue);
```

I would also use `ConfigureAwait(false)` if this were part of a data access layer, but since you're accessing `response.Content` directly I assume that you'll need the ASP.NET context later in this method.

Since you're new to `async` / `await`, you may find my [`async` / `await` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.